# SED not updating with complex regex

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to automate updating the version number in a file as part of build process.  I can get the following to work, but only for version numbers with single digits in each of the Major/minor/fix positions.

`sed -i 's/version="[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]"/version="2.4.567"/g' projectConfig.xml`

I've tried a more complex regex pattern and it works in the MS Regular Xpression Tool, but won't match when running sed.

`sed -i 's/version="\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"/version="2.4.567"/g' projectConfig.xml`

**Example Input:**

```
This is a file at version="2.1.245" and it consists of much more text.
```

**Desired output**

```
This is a file at version="2.4.567" and it consists of much more text.
```

I feel that there is something that I'm missing.

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: sed doesn't support `\d` , you'd need to use ERE to use `{}` as metacharacters, etc... see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: your sample input doesn't have double quotes but your attempted regex has it.. also, `"\b[0-9]` can be simplified to `"[0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems:

To enable quantifiers (`{}`) in `sed` you need the `-E` / `--regexp-extended` switch (or use `\{\}`, see http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions)

The character set shorthand `\d` is `[[:digit:]]` in `sed`.

Your input does not quote the version in `"`.

```
sed 's/version=\b[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\b/version="2.4.567"/g' \
    <<< "This is a file at version=2.1.245 and it consists of much more text."
```

To stay more portable, you might want to use the `--posix` switch (which requires removing `\b`):

```
sed --posix 's/version=[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}/version="2.4.567"/g' \
   <<< "This is a file at version=2.1.245 and it consists of much more text."
```